# Cloning Return Streams

Tags: replication

How would one go about cloning/replicating returns of a hedge fund or a strategy. That is given a return series of the object to be clone, is it possible to decompose return and reconstruct another different passive strategy that generates return that are correlated above 75%+? **Perfect replication is definitely not possible**, but I wanted to understand the process and possibly the success people have had in this area.

My initial thought on such subject would be to decompose its return using factor models...

Some pictures (source: bwater):
Edit: 2012-12-14[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reliable 75%+ correlation is definitely not possible for the vast majority of hedge fund types.

Comment: i beg to differ, there are lot of hedge funds that are dominated by beta rather than alpha. B-water did two piece of analysis and found that excess hedge fund return is practically flat since '09. Also they were able to replicate some strategy with 80% correlation (ie Emerging market hedge funds)

Comment: If you're suggesting not being restricted by a style, then yes it would be very easy to weight/select a portfolio to match any number.  I'm not sure what forward thinking solutions doing that could possibly bring however.

Comment: I am trying to figure out ways to tap in to different lowly correlated return streams to help diversify existing portfolios. And it seems hedge fund is a good place to start given their diverse market exposure.

Comment: Replication via factor or style attribution at rho > 0.8 is not particularly difficult -- over the past. Not so easy looking forward, you'll always be trading last quarter's factor mix. Harry Kat's distributional replication approach might be worth a try, but none of the trading pools/allocations based on it have rung any bells, AFAIK.

Comment: I did not provide an answer because what you are attempting is unethical at the very least. I am sure there are tons of people who beg to differ. They say that to stay competitive you must do whatever it takes to stay afloat. Well, I respond that you have a fiduciary duty to your investors and also to yourself, and stealing others' ideas and basically investing money without putting your own brain at works to come up with trading strategies is not particularly original nor fulfilling your fiduciary duty as PM. I do not want to invest with PMs who stole ideas from others for...

Comment: ...lack of own ideas. Sounds pretty unprofessional if you ask me. Secondly as someone else pointed out, you are always behind the curve, nowadays HFs change and adjust their strategies so often that when you get your hands at decent amounts of return and risk data such HFs most likely already changed their style, weights, strategies. Thirdly, HFs have put in such poor performance over the past years (tendency: dropping further) that I am not sure why you would want to emulate what players with a weakening edge do. Downvote!!!

Comment: First and foremost, don’t make assumptions of who I am (PM), as I am merely a humble 21 year old undergraduate student with a passion for quantitative finance. : ] Second of all I am not stealing ideas from anyone. The majority of hedge fund strategies can be categorized in about 10 different styles. If I am stealing, hell where do you think all the hedge funds that are just starting out get their ideas from, mars?

Comment: What they differ is their way of fine dicing their particular strategy so it is customized to their appetite for risk or more precisely their investors. I am NOT interested in the specific parameters they operate in, rather I am generally interested in the broadly defined characteristics that contribute to each styles returns.  (Which is why I ACKNOWLEDGE the fact that perfect replication is not possible).

Comment: Your point on Hedge fund return being dismal, I totally agree. But this actually means there are more research to be done to understand such under performance which may help to navigate better from a portfolio allocation point of view.

Comment: In all honesty, all funds that try to generate absolute return get ideas from everyone else, its just that they sugar coat it with different adjectives so it seems they are doing something completely different. I guess none should, by your definition, invest in any hedge funds...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treading controversial waters. It's hard to summarize, but at the risk of oversimplifying, there are three broad schools of thought:

1. "Linear Models": Classic Examples are a string of papers from Jasmina Hasanhodzic
   and Andy Lo at MIT (scholar.google.com should give you plenty). For similar work related to Mutual Funds that you may be able to repurpose you should look at the classic "Sharpe Returns Based Style Analysis (aka RBSA)" upon which most linear approaches are based.
2. "Non Linear and 'Mystery' models': (i.e. details undisclosed) models. Classic example is from the infinitely entertaining Harry Kat et al (examples include "Tell Me What You Want, What You Really, Really Want!" but if you google it, you'll need to add some sort of hedge fund replication tag to avoid getting nothing but Spice Girls references)
3. "It's not easy": Classic examples here are hard to find, but the most eloquent (and imho unbiased) are from Amenc et al at EDHEC. Examples include "Performance of Passive Hedge Fund Replication Strategies"

The short version, sadly, is that the general feeling (amongst the majority of academics, at least imho) is that what you are asking about is not easy to truly "clone" :-( but check out the references above anyway, perhaps you'll spot something new and interesting.

Having said that, many academics (and, apparently, some of your commenters) feel that most hedge fund "alpha" is really beta disguised as alpha. In that case, depending on what you mean by "replicating returns of a hedge fund" you may or may not have an plausible task on your hands. Replicating the "beta" portion of a hedge fund may indeed be possible. The classic reference here is probably any of the string of papers by Fung and Hsieh (again, scholar.google.com is your best friend).

Bottom Line: it's a matter of opinion and if you had a more precisely stated question, you might get a more precise answer. I hope that helps at least a little :-)

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. the reason I think its possible is because hedge fund return is dominated by beta, and therefore it should in theory be replicable to a certain extend. I got the idea when I was reading a book that mentioned standard beta based asset classes' return can be separated between risk free, structural beta, and structural alpha. The only component that offers diversification is the structural alpha, all others that have risk return characters below the cash equity line can be in theory replicated by a mix of cash and equities. I may be interpreting it wrong.